# wpf : How to add items to autocompletebox dynamically?

Tags: c#, wpf, autocompletebox

I'm working on building a desktop application using c# wpf window in VS 2013.I have an `AutoCompleteBox`.How to add items to AutoCompleteBox dynamically and statically ?.

Comment: I'm new to this.I have not tried anything much.

Comment: The documentation is a good place to start.

Comment: @user3559120 If you google You will get thousands of results, try with one of those results and post the question if you have any issues

Comment: Try this article. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/79158/AutoCompleteBox-Binding-Custom-Objects

Answer (score 0):

This might help. 
Please specify first from where you want the data in the autocompletebox
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.autocompletebox(v=vs.95).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.autocompletebox%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling the data from a Web Service then have a look on this blog:
http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2008/11/autocompletebox-missing-guide/

Comment: I am not calling data from a web service.It's just a desktop application and not web app

Comment: okey i got your point u should check:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.autocompletebox.itemssource(v=vs.95).aspx    or  http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WindowsPhone/2012.2/CLR4.0/html/AutoCompleteBox_Binding_to_Data.html